# Nativescript Angular ActionBar does not change between Child components

Tags: angular2-routing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In my nativescript angular project in the Main Component I have two child components (TestComponent and Test1Component) each having two different implementations of an action bar in the two layouts.

My problem is that when I navigate between the two child components the action bar does not change in the view.

However when I navigate outside the Main component to a different component (Test2 Component) and from there I return to any of the two child components the action bar displays correctly. Can someone tell me how to get the action bar to show correctly when navigating between the two child components.

*Edit: On experimentation I found that the behavior happens when I add a SearchBar inside the action bar in TestComponent. Even when there is no searchBar in Test1Component - the search bar continues to show.*

My Code is as follows:

app.routing.ts

```
import { TestComponent } from "./test.component";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { Test1Component } from "./test1.component";
import { Test2Component } from "./test2.component";

export const AppRoutes: any = [
    {
        path: "main", component: AppComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "0", component: TestComponent },
            { path: "1", component: Test1Component },
            { path: "", redirectTo: "0", pathMatch: "full" },
        ],
    },
    { path: "", redirectTo: "main", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "other", component: Test2Component, pathMatch: "full" },
];
```

Test and Test1 Component (the 2 child components)  look like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'test1',
    templateUrl: `./test1.component.html`
        })
        export class Test1Component {

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        console.log("*********************** Now I am in test1 component *********************");
    }

    goToTest() {
        this.router.navigate(["/main/0"]);
    }

    goToOthers() {
        this.router.navigate(["/other"]);
    }
}
```

The Html layout for both components is similar with different layouts in the action bar in each

Test1Component.html

```
        <ActionBar title="Welcome to Test 1" backgroundColor="#f82462" color="white">
        </ActionBar>
   
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="Hi," textWrap="true"></Label>
        <Label text="Hey I am Test-1, don't confuse with Test" textWrap="true"></Label>
        <Button text="Go To Test" (tap)="goToTest()"></Button>
        <Button text="Go To Other" (tap)="goToOthers()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

Finally the parent layout is like this

```
<GridLayout rows="*, auto">
    <StackLayout row="0" orientation="vertical">
        <Label text="demo text"></Label>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

You can also look at this issue in my [githubrepo](https://github.com/anuragd7/bottomBarExample/tree/master/app)

Please Help!

Comment: Is there a reason for placing the `<ActionBar></ActionBar>` inside two nested `StackLayout`. Everywhere I have seen ActionBar in {N} + Angular it is **declared in the root** of the Component HTML.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov - Have removed the nested StackLayouts . The ActionBar changes on navigating between pages if there is nothing in the ActionBar. However  the moment I insert a SearchBar within the ActionBar in TestComponent, it (the SearchBar) continues to show in Test1Component.

Comment: I think the issue is that you have a `router-outlet` rather than a page-router-outlet. I think that this is how the `router-outlet ` works, imagine a inner container to which you simply change the content rather that do a full new Page creation (navigation)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two "main" pages. one is "mains" and the other is "app.component".
even though you bootstrap "mains" in you routing your'e pointing your start page to "appComponent". and there you use "router-outlet".

I think that is where your problem lays.

Comment: @MatanCp - not sure I follow -  Main is our root component and hence has a page-router-outlet. The app component contains the 2 child components  (Test and Test 1) which are rendered in its router-outlet. Test2 component is the other component rendered in the page-router outlet.

Comment: i don't think "mains" is actually used as your root component.
check it out, write there an "alert" or "console" and see if it is activated.
my root component is used in my router as well, as in the "bootstrap" of app.module.  in your case you use "appcomonent" as the lowest level in your router.

Comment: Just checked - console message on mains is working. Update this in the repo as well